# Hide Certain Events from Calendar Overlay

Tags: 2010, calendar, groups, sharepoint-calendar

Our top-level site has a company calendar. We use calendar overlay feature to show a few department-level (subsite) calendars on it. However, the department users (subsites) only want certain events to show up on the company calendar. Is there a way to make certain events private to users in the department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could've used a flag in the department list which sets Show in Top Level Calendar. Then create a view filtering by this value, and then use this view in the overlay. No Code!

Comment: This totally works. Saved me a huge amount of time!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a workflow that sends the chosen events to the top calendar. 
When you create an event you could use a checkbox "show in top level calendar" in the form that activates the workflow when checked and sends the event to the top level calendar.

Best regards
Jonathan

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Does this create a new event in the top-level calendar (new list item)?

Comment: Yes you can give the command to create a new event with the same properties on the top-Level calendar.